# 2D 45 degree angled Sloped tiles

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl

Here is my code that checks the type of tile. If its an inclined tile it then updates the
position of the character. As demonstrated in the photo my character does not move along the slope. What am I doing wrong?

```
bool Entity::PosValidTile(Tile* Tile, int tileX, int tileY)
{
    if(Tile->TypeID == TILE_TYPE_ANGLEUP)
    {
        int Slope, Intercept;
        int newY;

        Vector P1,P2;
        P1.X = tileX; P1.Y = tileY + TILE_SIZE;
        P2.X = tileX + TILE_SIZE; P2.Y = tileY;


        if(X + (Width/2) > tileX)
        {
            Slope = -(P2.Y- P1.Y) / (P2.X - P1.X);

            Intercept = Slope * (-P1.X + P1.Y);

            newY = Slope * ((X + Width/2) + Intercept);

            Y = (newY - Height);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demonstration]

The dimensions of the character are 48 X 96; which are Width and Height respectively. His origin like the tile, is at the upper left corner.

Here is how that function is used

```
bool Entity::PosValid(int NewX, int NewY)
{

bool Return = true;

int StartX  = (NewX + Col_X) / TILE_SIZE;
int StartY  = (NewY + Col_Y) / TILE_SIZE;

int EndX    = ((NewX + Col_X) + Width - Col_Width - 1)      / TILE_SIZE;
int EndY    = ((NewY + Col_Y) + Height - Col_Height - 1)    / TILE_SIZE;

if(Flags & ENTITY_FLAG_IGNOREMAP)
{
}else
{
    for(int iY = StartY; iY <= EndY;iY++)
    {
        for(int iX = StartX;iX <= EndX;iX++)
        {
            Tile* Tile = Area::AreaControl.GetTile(iX * TILE_SIZE, iY * TILE_SIZE);

            int atileY = iY * TILE_SIZE;
            int atileX = iX * TILE_SIZE;

            if(PosValidTile(Tile,atileX,atileY) == false)
            {
                Return = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(Flags & ENTITY_FLAG_MAPONLY)
{
}else
{
    for(int i = 0;i < (int)EntityList.size();i++)
    {
        if(PosValidEntity(EntityList[i], NewX, NewY) == false)
        {
            Return = false;
        }
    }
}

return Return;
}
```

The function that calls the previous one is my OnMove function.

```
void Entity::OnMove(float MoveX, float MoveY)
{
if(MoveX == 0 && MoveY == 0) return;

double NewX = 0;
double NewY = 0;

CanJump = false;

MoveX *= Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
MoveY *= Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();

if(MoveX != 0)
{
    if(MoveX >= 0)  NewX =  Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
    else            NewX = -Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
}

if(MoveY != 0)
{
    if(MoveY >= 0)  NewY =  Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
    else            NewY = -Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
}

while(true)
{
    if(Flags & ENTITY_FLAG_GHOST)
    {
        PosValid((float)(X + NewX), (float)(Y + NewY));

        X += (float)NewX;
        Y += (float)NewY;
    }else
    {
        if(PosValid((float)(X + NewX), (int)(Y)))
        {
            X += (float)NewX;
        }else
        {
            SpeedX = 0;
        }

        if(PosValid((float)(X), (float)(Y + NewY)))
        {
            Y += (float)NewY;

        }else
        {
            if(MoveY > 0)
            {
                CanJump = true;
            }
            SpeedY = 0;
        }
    }

    MoveX += (float)-NewX;
    MoveY += (float)-NewY;

    if(NewX > 0 && MoveX <= 0) NewX = 0;
    if(NewX < 0 && MoveX >= 0) NewX = 0;

    if(NewY > 0 && MoveY <= 0) NewY = 0;
    if(NewY < 0 && MoveY >= 0) NewY = 0;

    if(MoveX == 0) NewX = 0;
    if(MoveY == 0) NewY = 0;

    if(MoveX == 0 && MoveY  == 0)   break;
    if(NewX  == 0 && NewY   == 0)   break;
}
}
```

This function is then called in the main Loop Like so 
    OnMove(SpeedX,SpeedY);
The speeds are calculated as fallows

```
    SpeedX += AccelX * Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
    SpeedY += AccelY * Time::TimeControl.GetDeltaTime();
```

Comment: You should add some `return false` in your function. All execution paths should return something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving an "answer" but it probably better fit as a comment... a few points:

- First question, what's happening in the debugger? Do you even get in the `if`?
- I don't see a mention of `delta time` anywhere, it should be used to get smooth time dependent movement (not frame dependent)
- `PosValidTile` doesn't say much about what the function does... you seem to modify your `Entity` `Y` value but not the `X`? **if you don't move horizontally against the slope, it's normal that you don't go up either!**
- `TILE_TYPE_ANGLEUP` doesn't make much sense to me, as its "angle" is "down" if your character turns and goes from right to left
- I guess character movement is determined elsewhere? The heading of your character should be taken into account to know on which side of the slope you're going (your "next" `X`, which doesn't seem to be computed here)
- Is the function here incomplete? not all paths return a value

**Edit:** You posted new code where you use `PosValidEntity` using `NewX` and `NewY` - we don't see where these values are set to, but keep in mind that your `PosValidTile` seems to modify directly `Y`, not a "tentative NewY".

Also, I'm not too sure what your `Intercept` is supposed to do. Basically you have your `Slope` and you want to know how many pixels along the `X` axis you are, multiply the `Slope` by this relative value and then add the base `Y`. In your case `Slope` is **always** `TILE_SIZE / TILE_SIZE` -> `1` so finding your new `Y` should be as easy as something like - if it's not always `1`, simply multiply the relative `X` by that slope

```
Y = X + (Width/2) - tileX + tileY;
```

You take the `X` position of your character, add the `Half Width` and the remove the base `X` value of the tile, this gives you how far along the `X` axis you are on the slope. Since your slope is always `1`, you are as far along the `Y` axis as you are on the `X` axis, so if you `add` (or `subtract` in your case because I think higher values mean lower on the screen in your coordinates?) this value to your base `Y` you should get your `Y` value.

Comment: 1. Yes I get into the if statement.
2. deltatime is factored into the movement of the character in another function.
3. This function checks to see if the players position is valid on the tile he is colliding with
4. the character only moves to the right. this is a running type game. So you cannot control his direction.
5. TILE_TYPE_ANGLEUP is just the type of tile it is. it's how i check the kind of tile he is colliding with.
6. this is just one of the if statements the rest handle different tiles like blocks or passable etc. I took em out to reduce any confusion.

Comment: So your `X` is increased but not the `Y`? What usually sets the `Y`? do you have these two code paths running one after the other so that the slope value gets overwritten by the standard "on the floor" `Y`?

Comment: You do have a point though now that i read what you said. I am definitely not checking the x value that is supposed to be next. I'm only checking the current x value. Let me give this some more thought.
Ill post how i use this function for clarity I added it to the first post.

Comment: I tried this out
   " Y = X + (Width/2) - tileX + tileY;"
Still does not really follow the angle sort of pops up and stays stuck like before. I updated the original question with the rest of the code.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the code but it would be much easier if you just stepped through the code with a debugger and saw where your X/Y gets zero'd for a given frame, making the character stuck

Comment: Doing it as we speak. Ill let you know in a sec.

Comment: I changed it to this
   Y = (X + (Width/2)) - (tileX - (tileY - Height));

This is what the debugger shows:
   Y = (817 + (48/2)) - (864 - (1200 - 96));
                841   - (-240) = 1081 = Y

so Y = 1081.

Comment: Ok, and is this the right value? What prevents your `X` from getting bigger?

Comment: It isn't the right value. Its going up too far. almost more than half the actual size of the block. I can't figure out what's stopping my 'X' value

Comment: I'm sorry but it's almost impossible for us to tell at this point, use the debugger, it shouldn't be hard to see where your NewX or similar variable gets reverted or 0 or you position is declared invalid when it shouldn't

Comment: scratch that, I just found it. It get's reverted to 0 because PosValid Function is returning false while i'm colliding with the sloped tile. It's in the section of the OnMove function where it updates the X value : `if(PosValid((float)(X + NewX), (int)(Y)))
   {
    X += (float)NewX;
   }else
   {
    SpeedX = 0;
   }`

Comment: After the player gets pushed up slightly from the slope he stops because something returns false and it goes into the part `SpeedX = 0;`

Comment: Good, glad you found the answer!

Comment: It's returning false because for some apparent reason he is colliding with the ground tile below him. So the play by play, The character enters the slope goes up along the slope for a fraction of a second then shoots downward and stops mid slope.

Comment: OK the two checks were working against each other. true, false, true false, so i put a bool so that when one occurs the other wont. However the math for the slope is pushing the players at a downward angle instead of upwards.. our math is off!

Comment: Relative to the screen. (0,0) is at the upper left hand corner of the screen.

Comment: Fixed the equation to this `Y = (tileX) - ((X + (Width)) - (tileY - 48));` it works now, but i cant use Width/2 because it snags on the block tiles and causes it to stop. :( i guess ill have to hard code something to allow it passage idk.